# OpenCV c++ mouseevent not working/or very slow with wacom graphic device

Tags: c++, opencv, mouseevent, wacom

I want to draw something with opencv c++ using my wacom graphic device. I've written some code that works great with the mouse, but with the wacom graphic device it is only working sometimes and very slow. The problem is the EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN, which is only detected after a considerable time delay. Here is my code:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <list>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
const cv::Vec3b color_black{0, 0, 0};
const cv::Vec3b color_azure{255, 127, 0};


int width = 800;
int height = 600;
cv::Mat image = cv::Mat(cv::Size(width, height), CV_8UC3, color_black);

std::list<cv::Point> polygon;
bool isMouseDown = false;

void repaint(){
    cv::rectangle(image, cv::Rect(0, 0, width, height), color_black, 1);

    std::list<cv::Point>::iterator it = polygon.begin();
    if(it== polygon.end()){
        return;
    }
    cv::Point prev = *it;
    it++;
    while(it!=polygon.end() ){
        cv::line(image, prev, *it, color_azure, 2);
        prev = *it;
        it++;
    }
   //show the image
     imshow("My Window", image);
}

void CallBackFunc(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* userdata)
{
     if  ( event == EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN )
     {
          isMouseDown = true;
          polygon.clear();
          repaint();
          
     }
     else if ( event == EVENT_MOUSEMOVE )
     
     {
          if(isMouseDown){
                polygon.push_back(cv::Point(x,y));
                repaint();
          }
     }
     else if (event == EVENT_LBUTTONUP){
        isMouseDown = false;
     }
}



int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
     // Read image from file 
     

     //Create a window
     namedWindow("My Window", 1);

     //set the callback function for any mouse event
     setMouseCallback("My Window", CallBackFunc, NULL);

     //show the image
     imshow("My Window", image);

     // Wait until user press some key
     waitKey(0);

     return 0;

}
```

Comment: Does that wacom device behave like a standard mouse in other applications, like windows explorer (can you draw a rectangle around multiple files to select them)? Maybe also try the other flags from https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/d90/group__highgui__window__flags.html

Comment: use a proper GUI toolkit. OpenCV is not made for that. -- perhaps there are too many events generated from the device, choking OpenCV/your program up in some way. move the imshow() out of the event handlers and into the main loop. in event handlers, set a flag like "dirty = true;" then redraw+imshow+clear in the main loop. yes, that implies a waitKey() with non-zero wait time (say, 10 milliseconds). it's not harmful though to keep spinning. waitKey() contains a loop with sleep() calls for at least one backend I know.